# PHP send mail suddenly stop working

Tags: php, html, smtp

I have used the php mail function in the contact form of my site to send out emails. It can send out the email before that but recently, I noticed that it just stop working.

The debug log file displayed "535 5.0.0 Authentication Failed" problem that resulted disconnection from smtp.live.com:587. I already checked the mail function code and it does work fine.

Does anyone facing the same issue here? How can i possibly fix this? Thank you.

```
<?php
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$message = "Message is sent with the following mail";
$send = mail('meoevent@hotmail.com','Hi XD',$message, $headers);
if ($send)
  echo "Yes";
else
  echo "No"; echo error_get_last();
?>
```

Here is my debug.log file

16/05/15 15:49:06 << 535 5.0.0 Authentication Failed
16/05/15 15:49:06 ** Disconnecting from smtp.live.com:587
16/05/15 15:49:06 ** Disconnected.
16/05/15 15:49:06 ** Disconnected.
16/05/15 15:49:06 ** Authentication Failed

Here is my mail function code.

Comment: function code :                                                                                       <?php
    
 $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
 
 $message = "Message is sent with the following mail";
 
    $send = mail('meoevent@hotmail.com','Hi XD',$message,$headers);

    if($send){
      echo "Yes";
 }
 else {
      echo "No";
   
   echo error_get_last();
 }

?>

Comment: You should use my suggested edit as it would help with better understanding of your code. :)

Comment: Well, sounds like your credentials for that smtp server are not accepted any more. You want to check that manually.

Comment: @arkascha, how to check the credentials of the smtp server ?

Comment: That depends on the smtp service provider, I'd say... You could give it a try using any standard email client program and configuring that smtp server for outgoing emails. I would expect you get some error message hinting what the issue is. Or, if you have some kind of account (which I assume), then check in there. Ask your service provider.

Answer (score 0):

Faced almost similar problem while using php [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function and found no fix. I would recommend you to use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) instead.